# Problem defaultCache and cache in distributed environment (Inconsistent data)

Tags: java, distributed, liferay, ehcache, replicate

Using the same configuration, with only defaultCache, I get inconsistent data (case A). But if I add an additional cache entry will not get those errors of inconsistency (case B).

Do you know why?

I do not want to set the 130 caches that set aumaticamente defaultCache

Thanks in advance

P. S. I guess all the time that what is not specified, will EHCache as a template using defaultCache settings.

Case A:

```
<defaultCache  
     maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
     eternal="false"  
     timeToIdleSeconds="0"  
     overflowToDisk="false"  

>  
    <cacheEventListenerFactory  
         class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"  

     />  
     <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />  
 </defaultCache>
```

`

Case B:

```
<defaultCache  
     maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
     eternal="false"  
     timeToIdleSeconds="0"  
     overflowToDisk="false"  

 >  
     <cacheEventListenerFactory  
         class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"  

     />  
     <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />  
 </defaultCache>  

 <cache  
     name="com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl"  
     maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
     eternal="false"  
     timeToIdleSeconds="0"  
     overflowToDisk="false"  
 >  
     <cacheEventListenerFactory  
         class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"  
     />  
     <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />  
 </cache>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't said how to you use cache it's hard to guess what you are really doing and what errors of inconsistency do you mean.

Maybe you are not caching query results with cached entities, which makes entities to be read from cache and queries from database? There are many possible cases.

Comment: This issue appears in liferay portal and i've identified it in Layout when i add a portlet in a machine of the cluster and i can't see it in another. As i said, if i put "case B" it works but in "case A" i see inconsistent data and i think that it should have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to run Liferay on the cluster env and got the same error: default config doesn't work.
I made some changes, maybe my config will help you.

[hibernate-clustered.xml](http://pastebin.com/pGsGCNqZ)

[liferay-multi-vm-clustered.xml](http://pastebin.com/ZDw1AiF0)

Comment: Difference is that we're not multicasting. We're doing a manual peerDiscovery and adding manually each cache that defaultCache is creating(previously listed because it's impossible to know which they're). Now we've found inconsistent data issues but not in each cache. It's very strange :S